# Regex Pattern For HTML Tags

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've been trying to find a pattern that extract the HTML between >< from the below:

```html
<li><a href="/web/20151030182314/https://www.wiki.edu/trees/">Forest Trees Green</a></li>

<span class="field-content">Tress, Design &amp; Plants</span></div> 

<h3><a href="http://web.archive.org/web/20151030182501/http://www.latimes.com">Trees</>
<div class="tf-text">
        Trees provide oxygen <a
<h4>Trees</h4>
<span class="field-content">Trees everywhere</span>  </div></li>
  </ul></div>    </div>
<h3 class="secondary-feature-headline">Through European Security Initiative, Stanford focuses on changing trees</h3>
```

Anybody have any suggestions? P.S I cannot use BeautifulSoup

Comment: I guess you want to look into beautifulsoup (https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python)

Comment: Why use a regex for this? Python has real HTML parsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Comment: [Do not use regex to parse html](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ṛ̭̲̪͗̏͒ē̯̭͓̲̜ͫͣͭͅg̻̘͇͕͎̠E̝̝̩͔͎͇̣̿ͨ͗́ͦx̭̙͇ ̫̒͆͌̆̃̐m͙̙͍͚͊̓ͥ͋ạ̞̺̣̻̬͉̃ͧ̓͌ͥͬ́t̿̈́c̍̇̑̒h̝͗̈ͮ́ ͓̻̟ͤ̆ͬ̅ͨ̌o̳̣̟̖̅̀̇ͪ̒p̣̤̑̔ͮe̠̞͚͉̫̽̌ͫ͂̒nͧ ̯̲̳̥̯t̙ͯ̐a̿͆͆ͥg͍̰̯̦̘̮͋̉̐̊̎͑̚ș̮̼̤͔͉͈ͮ̎ͪ ̮̟̞̜͋͒̅̓ͨeͨ̂x͍͔͕̼̭̥̣ͫͪ̑ͦ̐͒c̪͇̓̃͛ͣ̇e͓͎̜̎̒͂̿̀͗͛p̦̳͓̗ͣ͛̎͋̚t͔̯̙̪̘ͨ͋̿̂ͧ ͙̫͕̭̜̰ͦ̓͒̃̉̎̚X͓͉̮̲̬H̝̩̟̭͊ͫͦ̀̔T̘̳̯̺͖̪̤̅M̟̭͙̖̗̝̮ͭͬ̒͌̆͂L͓̥̍͌̑̏ ̮̝̝̗̓̀̇s͈̘͈͖͐̉̐̄̐̾e͓͍̖̬̋ͤl̹̼ͤ̾̀ͬ̀ͭ̌f͓͈̖̃ͩͨ͊̈-̘̲cͬ̓o̙ͤ́n͔̗̺ͫ̒̋͌t̗̺̠͈̀̀ͬͯ͊á̬̣̥̩̘̠ͫ̒i̪̔ͦͫñ͓͓̊̌͑̒̏ͩe̞͕͐ͩ̄ͬd̫̿̂̒ͯͯ̿͐ ̏̔ͣͧt͍͖̘͔̥̼ͦa̼͙ͥ̅ͪg̥̣͍̥̗̭͉̊ș̗̣̞̟͐͆ͦͫ͒̉̊](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348)

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup for extracting results, or normal regex module for text extraction,

```
import re
data = re.findall(r'>.*?<', text_content)
for string in data:
     sub = string.replace('>', '').replace('<', '').strip()
     if sub:
         print(sub)
```

The output for above text are as follows:

```
Forest Trees Green
Tress, Design & Plants
Trees
Trees
Trees everywhere
Through European Security Initiative, Stanford focuses on changing trees
```